# error while executing npm test - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'protractor'

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am learning angular and e2e and wanted to find out if anyone 
can point me in the right direction with the error i got.
I followed thru this tutorial found at 
http://www.webdriverjs.com/protractor-example-with-typescript/

everything worked great with config.js but i started having issues 
with typescript execution...

i suspect something is wrong with package.json but not sure what.
from reading stuff, there are different ways of configuring the package.json file like with versions and stuff... but i am new to protractor and can't figure out why some have the devdependencies, and some dont etc...

any help with this is greatly appreciated

here is the error i am getting when executing - npm test

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation>npm test`

> protractorautomation@1.0.0 pretest
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation npm run tsc
>
> protractorautomation@1.0.0 tsc
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation tsc
>
> error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'protractor'.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "tsc" npm ERR! node v6.11.4
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   protractorautomation@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the protractorautomation@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the
>   protractorautomation package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR!
>   Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     tsc npm
>   ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
>   with: npm ERR!     npm bugs protractorautomation npm ERR! Or if that
>   isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   protractorautomation npm ERR! There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation\npm-debug.log npm ERR!
>   Test failed.  See above for more details.

my folder structure:

Folder "ProtractorAutomation" consists of these folders/ files

- Folder ConvertedJSFiles
- Folder node_modules
- Folder specs

And files:

- config.ts
- config.js
- npm-debug
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

i tried to debug and ran some commands that added a lot of modules to
node_modules directory

Here are the key files

---

package.json

---

```
{
  "name": "protractorautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor Typescript automation framework",
  "main": "config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2"},
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "protractor ConvertedJSFiles/config.js",
     "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Protractor",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

---

tsconfig.json

---

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "ConvertedJSFiles",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node", "protractor"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

---

config.ts = inside specs folder

---

```
import { ProtractorBrowser, Config } from 'protractor';
export let config: Config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
    //'browserName':'firefox'
    },
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['./specs/**/*.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
  },
  onPrepare: () => {
   let globals = require('protractor');
   let browser = globals.browser;
   browser.manage().window().maximize();
   browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
 }
}
```

---

config.js  = inside specs folder

---

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'chrome'
//    'browserName': 'firefox'

    },
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['./specs/FirstSpec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

---

FirstSpec.ts = inside specs folder

---

```
import { ElementFinder, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function () { //Suite in 

Jasmine
  it('should add a todo', function () { // Test in Jasmine
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org'); // Entering application url in 

browser
    // Enter text under TODO
    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first 

protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click(); // Clicks on 'Add' button
    // Getting all Todo lists displayed
    element.all(by.repeater('todo in')).then(function (todoList) {
      // Asserting the TODO's count as 3
      expect(todoList.length.toString()).toEqual('3');
      todoList[2].getText().then(function (text) {
        //Verifying newly entered TODO is added
        expect(text).toEqual('write first protractor test');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

FirstSpec.js = inside specs folder - this is when i just run config.js

---

```
//Suite in Jasmine
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  // Test in Jasmine
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    // Entering application url in browser
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');
    // Enter text under TODO input field

//in the html code this element is :
//<input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText" size="30"
// placeholder="add new todo here" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty 

ng-touched">
    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first 

protractor test');

    // Clicks on 'Add' button
    // line in code where button is
    //<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">  WHY 

BY.CSS???
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    // Getting all Todo lists displayed
    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    // Asserting the TODO's count as 3
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    //Verifying newly entered TODO is added
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor 

test');
  });
});
```

---

config.js = inside ConvertedJSFiles

---

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
        //'browserName':'firefox'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['./specs/**/*.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        var globals = require('protractor');
        var browser = globals.browser;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
    }
};
```

---

FirstSpec.js = inside ConvertedJSFiles/Specs

---

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var protractor_1 = require("protractor");
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function () {
    it('should add a todo', function () {
        protractor_1.browser.get('https://angularjs.org'); // Entering application url in browser
        // Enter text under TODO
        protractor_1.element(protractor_1.by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
        protractor_1.element(protractor_1.by.css('[value="add"]')).click(); // Clicks on 'Add' button
        // Getting all Todo lists displayed
        protractor_1.element.all(protractor_1.by.repeater('todo in')).then(function (todoList) {
            // Asserting the TODO's count as 3
            expect(todoList.length.toString()).toEqual('3');
            todoList[2].getText().then(function (text) {
                //Verifying newly entered TODO is added
                expect(text).toEqual('write first protractor test');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

here are the versions

node -v
v6.11.4

npm -v
3.10.10

protractor --version
Version 5.1.2

i ran some commands to update/install typings and got lots of folders inside node_modules....

Thanks
DH

**Update after executing npm install** 
Thanks, I tried it, but still get an error...  here are the files in Directory of C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation

```
10/23/2017  09:58 AM    <DIR>          .
10/23/2017  09:58 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/22/2017  08:23 PM               288 config.js
10/22/2017  08:23 PM               547 config.ts
10/22/2017  07:17 PM    <DIR>          ConvertedJSFiles
10/22/2017  11:01 PM    <DIR>          node_modules
10/23/2017  09:54 AM             5,706 notes_files-questions.txt
10/23/2017  12:22 AM               517 package.json
10/22/2017  07:31 PM    <DIR>          specs
10/22/2017  11:03 PM               353 tsconfig.json
               5 File(s)          7,411 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  358,075,498,496 bytes free

C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: @types/jasminewd2@^2.2.0
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'protractorautomation'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation\npm-debug.log
```

C:\Users\username\Desktop\ProtractorAutomation>npm install

Comment: You need to install protractor first to run your e2e scripts. run `npm install` from the directory where the `package.json` file is present.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but still get an error...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this, by running it on another pc. I think my mistake was with the folders. Followed tutorial again, changed the protractor version from 4 to 5 inside package.json file and it worked.